# Using Java To Upload Video via PUT

Tags: java, video, file-io, upload

I am writing a Java app that uploads image and video files to a server side script. So far I've got the image upload happening using HTTPURLConnection/DataOutputstream and it seems that I might be able re-use a good deal of the code I've written to also upload the video. My question is, where the following snippet declares that the Content-Type is "image/jpeg" for images, what Content-Type should be use used for video files?

output.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"filename\" \r\n**Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n**Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n");

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type is the video?  You should be able to choose a specific Mime Type for the video in question.

See I[nternet Media Type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) at WikiPedia and also the [IANA registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/video/) for video mime types

Comment: Good question.. it's a quicktime file (.mov).